# Power BI Service Enable in Azure

Tags: azure, powerbi

I want to enable Power BI Service in Azure. I want to use my asp.net application to run the Power BI reports via azure. For this I want to add Power BI service in Azure. If I have organization user in Azure, will Power BI Service will be available in Azure?

Answer (score 2):

Most of Azure services can be used with Power BI

Whether your data are stored in:

- Azure SQL Database
- Azure SQL Data Warehouse
- Azure Marketplace
- Azure HDInsight
- Azure Blob Storage
- Azure Table Storage
- Azure HDInsight Spark
- Azure DocumentDB
- Azure Data Lake Store

You can absolutely get your insights, charts, etc. using Power BI APIs.

---

**Links**

- [Azure and Power BI](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-azure-and-power-bi)
- [Getting you started with Power BI development](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn889824.aspx)
- [Data Analytics Scenarios using Azure](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=535031&clcid=0x409)
- [Power BI Developer Portal](http://dev.powerbi.com/)
- [Power BI developer blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev)

Comment: What is the requirements to enable PowerBI Service in Azure. Whether it is possible in free trial subscription or we need to buy it?

Comment: You can absolutely try everything during your free trial.

Answer (score 0):

Hey buddy first You need to register your app with Azure Active Directory for that you need to visit the link that we are mentioning here [Register an app here](https://dev.powerbi.com/apps). Once you visit the link you need to follow the following steps.

1. Login to your Power BI account
2. Tell us about your app (App Name, App Type, Redirect URL and Home Page URL)
3. Choose API to access (DataSet API's, Report and Dashboard API's and other API's)

After providing the above details you need to click on the register app button that will provide you a Client ID and Client-secret ID. Also, this process will automatically enable the Power Bi service in Azure Active Directory, You can check it in the Azure portal.